# Rounded corners in a tree menu

Tags: jquery, css

I've come across this issue when I tried to put rounded corners for a tree menu with some background for the menu items. Please find a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/WqGgh/.

HTML code

```
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Menu One</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Menu One</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Two</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Three</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expanded">
            <span>Menu Two</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Menu One</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Two</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Three</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Menu Three</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Menu One</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Two</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Three</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
            <span>Menu Four</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Menu One</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Two</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Three</li>
            </ul>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS code

```
.tree {
border: 1px solid #bababb;
border-radius:4px;
width: 300px;
}
.tree ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.tree ul li span{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 20px;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    border-top: 1px solid #bababb;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.tree ul li:first-child span{
    border-top: none;
}

.tree ul ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 20px;
    border-top:1px solid #bababb;
}

.tree ul ul li.hover{
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

.tree ul li ul{
    display: none;

}

.tree ul li.expanded ul{
    display: block;
}

.tree ul li.expanded span{
    background: #e1e2e3;
}
```

JS code

```
$(function(){
$('.tree ul li span').click(function(){
    $('.tree ul li').removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('expanded');
});


$('.tree li').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
});
$('.tree li').bind('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I've come across this issue" - what issue? what is the problem?

Comment: what issue do you want to say?

Comment: @Juhana yeah you are right. It may be a duplicate question with a different approach

Comment: The corners are not very clear. @magnum2002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happened to be very simple. I just added **overflow: hidden** for the class *tree*. It solved my problem. I've checked in browsers like IE9, IE10, FF, Chrome, Opera in Windows and FF, Safari, Chrome in Mac OS.  Please find here http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/WqGgh/1/

```
.tree {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks for all the responses. Appreciated them.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue i can think of is the "missing" border color in the corners...

If this should be the problem: the background-color of the children overlies the border-color of the corners.

You have to give the first and last ".tree ul li span"-elements the same border-radius and border-color the ".tree"-container has.

```
.tree ul li span:first-of-type {
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:15px;}

.tree ul li + li span:first-of-type {
    border-radius:0px
}

.tree ul li span:last-of-type {
    border-bottom-left-radius:15px !important; /* instead of "!important you should use another selector for higher specificity to overwrite the preceding ".tree ul li + li span:first-of-type"-definition */
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px !important;
}
```

Comment: I have this fix but I wanted to do it in possibly better way. I got something. I just need to cross check. I'll post it back once I'm satisfied. Thanks anyways!